# Best method of displaying Google Calendar Events

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, mobile-website

I'm developing a mobile website for a gym as part of a self learning project.
Part of this project is adding a timetable that updates from a Google calendar.
I want to display the title of the event, the time it is on and a description.

My calendar will be updated as new events are added and removed from the schedule.

I have read through the Google Calendar V3 API and I have tried using coreylib as well.

I am looking for a step by step tutorial to set up and use the Google api correctly.
Or any other other method that will work.

I am a complete beginner when it comes to google APIs and web development.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend storing the events with the date in a table. Then, display the event to the user on that particular page by grabbing that information in a select.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_php